# How do I get a user's email address using accounts-facebook in Meteor?

Tags: facebook, meteor, user-accounts

I created a Meteor app that allows users to sign on using Facebook. To do this, I'm using the accounts-ui and accounts-facebook packages. This works fine.

How do I retrieve the user's email address once they've signed on? I understand that this requires special permission, and so I added `email` as a "User & Friend's Permission" in the app settings on the Facebook developers site. Following the Meteor documentation, I also set up `Account.ui.config` like this:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    facebook: ['email'],
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
});
```

As expected, when a user of my app signs on using Facebook, it correctly asks them to share their email address. But how do I retrieve it? The user document has only the `_id` and `profile.name`.

Comment: When using `accounts-facebook`, you don't need to configure the `accounts-ui` with those permissions - email and basic info are  requested by default. `passwordSignupFields` is only used for regular accounts, not for Facebook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Facebook user's email address is stored in `[userDocument].services.facebook.email`, which is not published to the client, but can be accessed from the server or from the client using `Meteor.methods` and `Meteor.call`.

Comment: And you could publish the email field on the server using eg. `Meteor.publish("facebook_email", function() { return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'services.facebook.email': 1}}); });`, taking care to only publish the user's email to the client for that user to prevent privacy issues.

Comment: Does anybody know the syntax for getting the facebook picture?  I tried the following, and variations thereof, with no luck:  `Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields:{'services.facebook.picture.data.url': 1}});`

Answer (score 0):

this will add the Facebook profile info to the client side user object.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser (options, user) ->    

    if options.profile
        user.profile = options.profile

        # get profile data from Facebook
        result = Meteor.http.get "https://graph.facebook.com/me", {
                  params: access_token: user.services.facebook.accessToken} 

        if  !result.error && result.data
            #if successfully obtained facebook profile, save it off
            #the user can access the profile object on the client
            user.profile.facebook = result.data;

    return user
```

on the server side the facebook.accesstoken can be accessed... so use it to get the full FB info and save it to the client user object..

ping a Meteor.user() in the console now to get the FB info.

dont think this is exactly best practice in terms of having FB info on the client..

Comment: By doing it this way (nice out of the box thinking, btw) you're circumventing Meteor's publishing system, which probably isn't a good path to go down to as your code will be less predictable. See JWS' answer for the Meteor-recommended approach.